In the context of delta-V budgets, what does C3 = 0 mean?
Wikipedia has the following article on delta-V budgets, which I'm trying to understand.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v_budget
Several times the condition C3 = 0 is included in abbreviations and tables, but I can't find a an explanation for what C3 is or the meaning of the condition C3 = 0.
TIA

See: Characteristic energy.
